SQL Server variable creation
I have the following query in SQL Server, I am trying to create variables dynamically
DECLARE @TESTEO     NVARCHAR(max)
SET @TESTEO = '
DECLARE @SEG1HEM    NVARCHAR(max)
SET @SEG1HEM    = (SELECT REGION        FROM PRUEBA..L3_PRESENTACIONES_OUTLETS_TB WHERE OUTLET_CODE = ''1156'')
PRINT @SEG1HEM
'
EXEC sp_executesql @TESTEO
PRINT @SEG1HEM

Is it possible to create the variable ("@SEG1HEM") in this way and use this variable ("@SEG1HEM") outside of this dynamic script?

Why do you need dynamic SQL here when there's nothing dynamic about your statement?

You cannot declare a variable dynamically but you can assign dynamicaly generated value to it. Use sp_executesql OUTPUT parameters. Google will tell you how to do it.
